# How To DROP auto increment from a column in sybase

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

So, I have a column that initial setting was INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO-INCREMENT in a ASA16 database. but I want to drop AUTO-INCREMENT setting, so the only setting that will be left are INTEGER and NOT NULL

initial setting was =

```
ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" MODIFY "XID" INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT
```

Note = XID is Primary Key

So, I already tried using this code :

```
ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" MODIFY "XID" INTEGER NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" ADD PRIMARY KEY ( "XID" ASC );
```

but auto-increment setting is still there

Anyone know how to do that? TO DROP or DELETE auto increment setting from that column for ASA16?

ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" MODIFY or DELETE ?????????????

Can someone help me?

Comment: ASA is used for versions 6-9, 10 and newer are called SQL Anywhere.  I have corrected your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE "USERVARIABLE" MODIFY "XID" DEFAULT NULL
```